# Reference actions form mixing in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js

So I have a mixing with some view-accessible methods and some private ones...

```
# mixin.coffee
App.LinkParsing = Em.Mixin.create
  method1: ->
    alert "foo"

  actions:
    method2: (link) ->
      alert "too #{link}"

    method3: (link) ->
      @method2(link)
      # and some other stuff...
```

Method 2 and 3 are in the `actions` object so they're accessible in views.

```
# view.handlebars
<a {{bindAttr href="url"}}{{action method3 this}}>foo</a>
```

I need method 3 to be accessed on click, but for it to have access to method2.

The issue is, inside method3, I get

*undefined is not a function: **this.method2***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `send` to call functions in the `actions` hash.

```
this.send('method2',link);
```